# Java - download a file through network with a buffer

Tags: java, network-programming

i want to read from a network stream and write the bytes to a file, directly.
But every time i run the program very few bytes are written to the file actually.

Java:

```
InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
int clength=uc.getContentLength();
byte[] barr = new byte[clength];
int offset=0;
int totalwritten=0;
int i;
int wrote=0;

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("file.xlsx");
while(in.available()!=0) { 
   wrote=in.read(barr, offset, clength-offset);
   out.write(barr, offset, wrote);
   offset+=wrote;
   totalwritten+=wrote;
}
System.out.println("Written: "+totalwritten+" of "+clength);
out.flush();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because [available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) doesn't do what you think it does. Read its API documentation. You should simply read until the number of bytes read, returned by [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29), is -1. Or even simpler, use [`Files.copy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29):

```
Files.copy(in, new File("file.xlsx").toPath());
```

Using a buffer that has the size of the input stream also pretty much defeats the purpose of using a buffer, which is to only have a few bytes in memory.

If you want to reimplement `copy()`, the general pattern is the following:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // number of bytes in memory
int numberOfBytesRead;
while ((numberOfBytesRead = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
}
```

Comment: the line 4 of the snippet shouldn't be an offset variable instead of 0?

Comment: No. Read the api doc (again): *The first byte read is stored into element b[0], the next one into b[1], and so on. The number of bytes read is, at most, equal to the length of b.*

Comment: absolutely correct. Thanks. so the zero in line 4 is for offset in table not in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You're using .available() wrong. From [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()):

> available() returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read
>   (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next
>   invocation of a method for this input stream

That means that the first time your stream is slower than your file writing speed (very soon in all probability) the while ends.

You should either prepare a thread that waits for the input until it has read all the expected content length (with a sizable timeout, of course) or just block your program in the wait, if user interaction is not a big deal.